# How to permanently disable the recent search history in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I know we can remove them but how to disable it permanently?

[image: Recent Graph Search history]

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, Facebook does not provide an option to stop remembering your searches and then displaying them for you again in your recent searches.

You'll notice that the [official help article](https://www.facebook.com/help/382661798450396) subtly discourages you from even bothering to delete recent search entries at all. Basically, Facebook insists that you use this feature.

Wish I had better answer for you.